# Using JS to Measure an Image Height and use in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, image

I would like to set the width of a div based on the width of an image that has been scaled to fit the viewing screen.

Now, I'm not a platinum grade programmer, but from what I gather this may be done using JavaScript to measure the width of the image and then outputting that result to the CSS.  However I have no clue how to do this and can't find any decent tutorials.  If anyone could point me to a tutorial or another good method for achieving my end that would be lovely.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JS (no jQuery) you can use `style.width` and `offsetWidth`. For example:

```
var w = document.getElementById('img_id').offsetWidth;
document.getElementById('div_id').style.width = w + 'px';​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Where `'img_id'` is the `id` of the `img`, and `'div_id'` is the `id` of the `div`.

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p6n2B/).

Answer (score 2):

This is very easily done with jQuery...

`$('div').css( 'width', $('img').width() + 'px' );`

See [.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Wcp9d/).

Comment: This is really helpful.  Thank you.  And how would I pass this to css?

Comment: This would apply an inline style: `<img src="..." style="width:123px;">`. You cannot modify .css files after the page has been rendered.